# read handle problem

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am working on network programming using epoll and I have this code...

```
int read = read(socket, buf, bufsize);
```

I have a huge buffer size and I assumed it will receive everything clients sent. 
However, I started facing problems like packet segmentation.

One example is that if a client sent 500 bytes but it somehow got into two 250 bytes packets then there is no way to handle this situation.

I looked up online and found this code

```
int handle_read(client *cli, struct epoll_event *ev) {
    size_t len = 4096;
    char *p;
    ssize_t received;

    cli->state = 1;
    if (cli->buffer != NULL) {
        //free(cli->buffer);
        //printf("Buff not null %s\n", cli->buffer);
    }

    //allocate space for data
    cli->buffer = (char*)malloc( (size_t)(sizeof(char) * 4096) );
    p = cli->buffer;

    do { //read until loop conditions
        received = recv(ev->data.fd, p, len, 0);
        if (received < 0 && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
            //if error, remove from epoll and close socket
            printf("Handle error!!!\nClient disconnected!\n");
            epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, ev->data.fd, ev);
            close(ev->data.fd);
        }
        p = &cli->buffer[received];
    } while (received >= len && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK);

    return received;
}
```

Do you guys think it handles all the exceptions might happen while receiving? Also could you please provide me tutorials or examples that handles socket exceptions? Sample codes online don't cover details.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` can return any of *three* things, and your code needs to handle each one correctly:

1) Positive number.  This means it read some bytes.

2) Negative number.  This means an "error" occurred.

3) Zero.  This means the other end of the connection performed a successful `shutdown()` (or `close()`) on the socket.  (In general, a return of 0 from read() or recv() means `EOF`.)

The "error" case further breaks down into "`EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`" and "everything else".  The first two just means it is a non-blocking socket and there was no data to give you at this time.  You probably want to go back and call poll() (or select() or epoll()) again to avoid busy waiting...

"Everything else" means a real error.  You need to handle those too; see the [POSIX spec for recv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) for a complete list.

Given all this, I would say your sample code is bad for several reasons.  It does not handle 0 (closed connection) properly.  It does not handle any errors.  It does a busy-loop when the `recv()` returns `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.

Oh, and it uses `sizeof(char)`, which is a sure sign it was written by somebody who is not familiar with the C or C++ programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know any good sample code or tutorial? I looked online and they covered just basic stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not off-hand...  I always just roll my own.  It's a pretty simple nested if/then structure to handle all of the cases, but _how_ you want to handle each case depends on the particular application.  (In particular, the errors.  Do you return a code or throw an exception?  Well, that depends on your own conventions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't know "How many datas client sent" in normaly. you should use scalable data format(that have data length in the header) or separator for data tokens. For example, you may add \xff between data and next data. Or, you should use fixed data format.